# Drives Going Offline While Adding Nodes to a Cluster

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

I have two physical servers Server A and Server B in the same domain and a single subnet. For setting up "Always On High Availability", I created a cluster on Server A. While adding another node i.e., Server B to this cluster, I observed all the local disks in both the nodes are going OFFLINE. It happened thrice till now, for which I had to destroy the cluster and restart the machines.

Please let me know a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the node to the failover cluster with the wizard, on the Confirmation step window by default there is this **Add all eligible storage to the cluster.** option checked by default, you need to uncheck it.

Check this [blog](https://blog.greglow.com/2016/05/02/avoiding-drives-going-offline-when-adding-nodes-to-availability-groups-or-creating-validating-windows-clusters)